# Migrating Facebook API for URL share count from v1.0 to v2.0+

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I am maintaining the [WordPress Social Metrics Tracker plugin](https://github.com/chapmanu/wp-social-metrics-tracker). The plugin makes GET requests to various social network APIs, including Facebook, to retrieve the number of times a URL has been shared.

This plugin currently uses v1.0 of the Facebook API which [is deprecated and will be removed on April 30, 2015](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog). I need to migrate to a newer version of the Facebook API, however it seems that Facebook has locked down their API to require access tokens.

The following data from Facebook is required:

- Number of Shares for a given URL
- Number of Likes for a given URL
- Number of Comments for a given URL

**The Question:**

What is the best way to retrieve this data from Facebook that requires the least level of authentication from the end-user of the plugin, and that uses at least API version 2.0?

Or, if authentication is required, can I avoid asking the user to sign in to Facebook to get it?

**Considerations:**

Because this is an open source WordPress plugin which gets distributed to user servers, no app secret or other sensitive data can live in the plugin source code anywhere.

Users of the plugin do not currently need to "sign in" or "sign up" - the plugin just works out of the box. It would be great to keep things that simple, however if asking users to "sign in to Facebook" is the only way to retrieve data from the Facebook API then so be it.

If we do need to retrieve an auth token, it will need to keep working in the background on the server and not have to prompt the user to re-authenticate.

**Existing API request examples:**

A GET request to this Facebook API endpoint works great and returns data:

[API v1.0 link example (works - currently used by plugin)](https://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/fql?q=SELECT%20url,%20share_count,%20like_count,%20comment_count,%20total_count,%20click_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20where%20url=%27http://www.wikipedia.org%27)

However, when we switch the version to v2.0 we are informed that an access token is required for the resource:

[API v2.0 link example (broken)](https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/fql?q=SELECT%20url,%20share_count,%20like_count,%20comment_count,%20total_count,%20click_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20where%20url=%27http://www.wikipedia.org%27)

And when we switch to v2.3, the latest version, we learn that the FQL queries have been removed from the API:

[API v2.3 link example (broken)](https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/fql?q=SELECT%20url,%20share_count,%20like_count,%20comment_count,%20total_count,%20click_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20where%20url=%27http://www.wikipedia.org%27)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The endpoint you're looking for is `/?id={url}`. The Graph API v2.3 requires at least an App Access Token for this, which would mean that your plugins' users must create an Facebook App first before being able to use this endpoint. This can be done via https://developers.facebook.com/apps/

A sample call would be

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/?access_token={app_access_token}&id=http://www.wikipedia.org
```

which results in

```
{
   "og_object": {
      "id": "382267859091",
      "title": "Wikipedia",
      "type": "website",
      "updated_time": "2015-04-14T23:28:48+0000",
      "url": "http://www.wikipedia.org/"
   },
   "share": {
      "comment_count": 0,
      "share_count": 195105
   },
   "id": "http://www.wikipedia.org"
}
```

As you noticed, the likes are missing.

You can get these by issueing a second call by using the returned `og_object.id` like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/382267859091?fields=likes.summary(true).limit(0)&access_token={app_access_token}
```

which results in

```
{
  "likes": {
    "data": [
    ], 
    "summary": {
      "total_count": 1298
    }
  }, 
  "id": "382267859091"
}
```

You can also do this in one Batch request:

```
POST https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3
```

with the field `batch` set to

```
[
    {
        "method": "GET",
        "name": "get-url-stats",
        "relative_url": "v2.3/?id=http://www.wikipedia.org",
        "omit_response_on_success": false
    },
    {
        "method": "GET",
        "name": "likes",
        "relative_url": "v2.3/{result=get-url-stats:$.og_object.id}?fields=likes.summary(true).limit(0)"
    }
]
```

and the fields `access_token` with your App Access Token. This returns a lengthy response like this (headers omitted for brevity):

```
[
  {
    "code": 200, 
    "headers": [
      ...
    ], 
    "body": "{\n   \"og_object\": {\n      \"id\": \"382267859091\",\n      \"title\": \"Wikipedia\",\n      \"type\": \"website\",\n      \"updated_time\": \"2015-04-14T23:28:48+0000\",\n      \"url\": \"http://www.wikipedia.org/\"\n   },\n   \"share\": {\n      \"comment_count\": 0,\n      \"share_count\": 195105\n   },\n   \"id\": \"http://www.wikipedia.org\"\n}"
  }, 
  {
    "code": 200, 
    "headers": [
      ...
    ], 
    "body": "{\n   \"likes\": {\n      \"data\": [\n         \n      ],\n      \"summary\": {\n         \"total_count\": 1298\n      }\n   },\n   \"id\": \"382267859091\"\n}"
  }
]
```

You have to parse each `body` property as JSON, and then use the data to create/show your stats.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/url
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests#operations

Comment: With the App Access Token, do I need to ask each plugin user to create an App on Facebook? Or can I just create one app and embed my access token in the plugin? I want to make it as easy as possible for plugin users to be able to get the data since creating an App on Facebook is a bit of a process. Wouldn't asking them to "Sign in with Facebook" be a simpler process than asking them to create an app?

Comment: Facebook advises not to share App Access Tokens for security reasons. My recommendation would be as I wrote: One application per plugin use.

Comment: I'm having another issue where the numbers returned by the v2.3 API are different than the numbers from the v1.0 API. If you know anything, more insight would be appreciated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29805025/facebook-api-versions-returning-different-shared-count

Comment: I'd recommend to open a bug with Facebook to get a clarification. Sorry that I can't say more.