# Facebook API versions returning different shared count

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Why is it that the Facebook API is returning a different **shared_count** and **comment_count** for the same URL depending on which version of the API I query?

**Graph API 1.0 (deprecated)**

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/fql?q=SELECT%20url,%20share_count,%20like_count,%20comment_count,%20total_count,%20click_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20where%20url=%27http://www.wikipedia.org/%27
```

Results in

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "url": "http://www.wikipedia.org/",
         "share_count": 73450,
         "like_count": 28937,
         "comment_count": 16637,
         "total_count": 119024,
         "click_count": 621935
      }
   ]
}
```

**Graph API 2.3 (current)**

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/?id=http://www.wikipedia.org/&access_token=SECRET_TOKEN_HERE
```

Results in

```
{
   "og_object": {
      "id": "382267859091",
      "title": "Wikipedia",
      "type": "website",
      "updated_time": "2015-04-21T21:22:59+0000",
      "url": "http://www.wikipedia.org/"
   },
   "share": {
      "comment_count": 3,
      "share_count": 199005
   },
   "id": "http://www.wikipedia.org/"
}
```

Also, sharedcount.com returns numbers which match the v1.0 API:

http://www.sharedcount.com/#url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikipedia.org%2F

[See my related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29680762/migrating-facebook-api-for-url-share-count-from-v1-0-to-v2-0)

Comment: SharedCount is using v1.0, therefore I don't expect any discrepancies...

Comment: For anyone with the same issue, I've found that [this bug has been reported to Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/864948553549113/). It is ambiguous if they are going to change the functionality or if it will remain the same. A Facebook employee recommended using this type of endpoint to retrieve the correct total count for all three fields: `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/?fields=share,og_object{engagement}&access_token=SECRET_TOKEN&id=http://www.wikipedia.org/`