# Is api.facebook.com here to stay or will it be deprecated along with Graph API v1.0?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on a project that requires getting the number of Likes and Shares of various links.

This can be done either by calling api.facebook.com or Graph API v1.0 in the public with no app and token required at all.

http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=http://www.example.com/
http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.example.com/

However, Facebook has [started deprecating apps using Graph API v1.0](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/api-v1-deprecation), and their Platform Upgrade Guide makes no mention of api.facebook.com which predates Graph API v1.0.

> Developers should expect apps calling API v1.0 to be migrated **at any time after April 30th, 2015**. The migration will roll out to all apps over the course of **a few weeks**.

Should I expect api.facebook.com to be deprecated along with Graph API v1.0, or will it be another `sharer.php` and be kept indefinitely?

Comment: To downvoters: From my understanding, although there's no code in this question, Facebook has been using facebook.stackoverflow.com, which is stackoverflow.com questions with facebook-* tags, as replacement of their Facebook Developer Forums and as one of their official developer support channels. Therefore, in this case, I was expecting information from someone from Facebook with knowledge of the API deprecation schedules. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/facebook-stackoverflow/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, apparantly the api.facebook.com server is regarded as v2.0, which is no longer available as of August 7th, 2016. All methods on api.facebook.com now return the `REST API is deprecated for versions v2.1 and higher (12)` error message.

Answer (score 1):

It's announced as deprecated since a long time ago. Probably nobody will be able to tell you WHEN or IF Facebook will shut it down. But assume that this can happen anytime.

So, if you don't want to have your app suddenly break, then you should migrate to Graph API v2.3.

Have a look at

- [Migrating Facebook API for URL share count from v1.0 to v2.0+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29680762/migrating-facebook-api-for-url-share-count-from-v1-0-to-v2-0/29693685#29693685)

Comment: Thanks for the link! I never knew it was still possible to get a separate Like/Share count with the newer versions of the Graph API, it was one of the reasons why I still wanted to use api.facebook.com.